# Display images with VueJS and Laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to display images with VueJS, but it either prints `{{ activity.image }}` or shows a compilation error. These are the attempts:

```
<img :src="'{{ activity.image }}'"> // Displays {{ activity.image }}
<img :src="{{ activity.image }}"> // Error
<img :src="'@{{ activity.image }}'"> // Displays @{{ activity.image }}

<img v-bind="src:'{{ activity.image }}'" alt=""> // Error
<img v-attr="src:'{{ activity.image }}'" alt=""> // Error

<img :src={{ activity.image }} alt=""> // Error
```

How do I do it?

Comment: where is `activity.image` coming from? Vue or PHP?

Comment: Can we see the script part of your code?

Comment: what's in activity object? can you paste that in your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume `activity.image` is coming from the JavaScript, since you're using the dot notation.

You can use `v-bind:src="activity.image"`, yes, without the mustache.

or if it came from PHP, you should be using the `->` operator.

`v-bind:src="{{ $activity->image }}"`, you need those mustache for the Blade rendering, however you don't need the mustache for the Vue.

Comment: `v-bind:src="activity.image"` was the solution. I don't think I'd ever think of it. Thank you.

Comment: remember when using `v-bind` you don't need to do interpolation a.k.a. `{{}}` :)

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
<img :src="'/images/'+item.images" alt="image" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add '/' before the link

Inside blade file:

```
<img src="{{ asset($table->img) }}">
```

Vue Component:

```
<img :src="'/' + table.img">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

*Note: img is in public folder*

```js
 
 <templete>
    <img :src="getImage()" class="card-img-top" alt="" />
 </templete>
 <script>
 export default {
           methods:{
                      getImage(){
                          return  'img/images.jpg';
                      }
                  }
             }
  </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly point to the image:

```html
<img src="/images/logo.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone has similiar problems. I use Vue2, with Vuetify2 and Laravel as my Backend. I tried to first show my image within my Blade file and afterwards with the right path in my Vue component to solve this problem. This worked for me:

**Inside my blade file**

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/aaa.jpg') }}">
```

**Vue Component**

```
<img src="images/aaa.jpg">
```

I tried various approaches with dynamic binding and so forth but this finally worked.