# How to add an image on a vue component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I tried add and image on my vue component :

```
<img src="/storage/app/product_images/up.png" alt="">
```

but i get this error:

[image]

and i am sure that the file exist.

[image]

this a `laravel / vue` project.

Comment: you can also pass image as base64 in API, just create an image in the backend and converted it into base64 and pass it, nobody knows about your project directory structure as well.

Comment: @GauravGupta why would you pass the images as base64? That will make the API responses bigger and slower. Since it's a Laravel app, the project structure is clear. He just needs to use the storage public dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try placing pictures in the public/img/

And in Vue component use path like this

```html
<img src="/img/product_images/up.png" alt="">
```

[Here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/display-image-from-laravel-public-folder-in-a-vue-component) you can see the details of my answer

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805549/display-images-with-vuejs-and-laravel) are other options for using pictures in a bundle of Laravel and Vue