# How to use relative paths in Vue.js dev environment

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, laravel-artisan, laravel-mix

I am having trouble with paths in the development and production environments in a `laravel`/`vue.js` project.

**In CSS files**:

Development environment `npm run hot` only accepts absolute paths in urls like `/public/images/image.png` while the production environment `npm run prod` + `php artisan serve` only accepts relative paths like `../images/image.png`.

When I try to use a `relative path` in `vue` the images are not shown in the browser and the console shows:

```
GET http://localhost:63342/images/image.png?ffda917d2a7141d8413f313bccf119c5 404 (Not Found)
```

**In vue templates**:

In order to being able to use `inline images` in production I had to wrap the path inside `require().default`:

```
<img :src="require('../images/image.png').default" class="emailIcon" alt="">
```

`require()` does not seem to work in the development environment though. When I `npm run hot` the images are not shown.

Browser console shows:

```
GET http://localhost:63342/images/image.png?ffda917d2a7141d8413f313bccf119c5 404 (Not Found)
```

specs:

```
Windows 10
Laravel: 8.55.0
Vue.js: 4.5.13
```

**Edit:**

From @Chandan's comment I found that `<img src="images/image.png">` works for both environments IF the `images` folder is inside `public`.

Unfortunately this doesn't work for `url("images/image.png")` if you want to put an image as `background`. Any insight there?

**Edit2:**

In the end there was no good solution for my problem. So I stopped using `npm run hot` and instead linked `npm run watch` to `php artisan serve`. Now I'm only using production server with `hot reload`. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49392001/laravel-project-auto-refresh-after-changes) how to set it up.

Comment: Your images should be in laravel public folder. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52576512/how-can-use-laravel-assets-in-vue-component) pls

Comment: @NikolaPavicevic I tried implementing that but it broke my project. Is there no way without writing new functions to "trick" the framework?

Comment: I just looked in one of my project. I put images in laravel public folder (not storage) and then in vue component `:src="images/'+imageName`"

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805549/display-images-with-vuejs-and-laravel).

Comment: @Chandan Thank you! Could you take a look at the **edit** section?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#url-processing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the image controller you can upload your image like this or save it in the storage folder:

```
$extension = $request->image->extension();
$request->image->storeAs("location","name of image".".".$extension);
$imageName = Storage::url("location//name of image").".".$extension);

Post::create([ // Or image or which model your using to store your images
    'image_path' => $imageName,
]);
```

and then create a symbolic link by run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then u can make a route like this:

```
Route::get('image/{slug}/',[App\Http\Controllers\ImageController::class, 'show'])->name('image.show');
```

And controller like this:

```
class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function show($slug)
    {
        // U can even make checks here if u want!
        $pathToFile = storage_path("location\\".$slug);
        return response()->file($pathToFile);
    }
}
```

And finally in PHP

```
<img src="{{url($image_path)}}"/>
```

or in JS

```
const src = window.location.origin + image_path;
```

And if the paths are correctly set the controller should return the image!

But this is if u want to implement a `private` foldor and want to make sure that user has to be logged in before accessing a image! but if ur folder is `public` you should just be able to do

```
    <div
            :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + data.image + ')' }"
    />
```